# Использование и трансформация объектов структуры System.Drawing.Point

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio, c#-7.3

Необходимо создать изображение на основе объектов структуры `Point`. Имеется два объекта

```
var orig = new Point(point.X, point.Y);
var inversed = new Point(size.Width - point.X - 1, point.Y);
```

Дак вот, можно ли объединить их в одну картинку, один объект структуры `Point`? Они создаются на основе одной картинки, просто первый объект - изначальная картинка, а второй - отражённая по горизонтали. Желательно также, чтобы это всё было в переменной.

Желаемый результат.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Создавая вот такой метод изображение отражается по горизонтали.

```
            mainForm.AddFilter(new TransformFilter(
                "Мозаика(Должна быть)",
                size => size,
                (point, size) =>
                {
                    
                    var orig = new Point(point.X, point.Y);
                    var inversed = new Point(size.Width - point.X - 1, point.Y);

                    return inversed;/*заглушка*/
                }
                ));
```

Метод является делегатом вот этого класса.

```
    public class TransformFilter : TransformFilter<EmptyParameters>
    {
        public TransformFilter(string name, Func<Size, Size> sizeTransformer,
            Func<Point, Size, Point> pointTransformer)
            : base(name, new FreeTransformer(sizeTransformer, pointTransformer)) { }
    }
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118483/discussion-on-question-by-------).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По сути здесь просто тот же пересчет координат.

```cs
mainForm.AddFilter(new TransformFilter(
    "Мозаика",
    size => size,
    (point, size) =>
    {
        point.X = (point.X < size.Width / 2 ? point.X : size.Width - point.X - 1) * 2;
        point.Y = (point.Y < size.Height / 2 ? point.Y : size.Height - point.Y - 1) * 2;
        return point;
    }
));
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118484/discussion-on-answer-by-aepot------s).